# jenkins pipeline : docker not found

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

i wanted to create a docker image with jenkins but docker not found

how can i add jenkins to docker groupe on windows ?
i tried to add docker plugin and didn't work

this is my pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options { buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr:'5'))}
    environment {DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS = credentials('tfkben-dockerhub')}
    stages {
            stage('build'){  steps {  sh 'docker build -t tfkben/ben:latest .' }  }
            stage('Login'){  steps {  sh 'echo $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW | docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR --password-stdin ' }}
            stage('Push'){  steps {  sh 'docker push tfkben/ben:latest'}   }                                 
         }                           
            post { always { sh 'docker logout' }}
}
```

my Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.11-rc-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and this is the error message :

- docker build -t tfkben/ben:latest .
  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/dockerhub-auth_master@tmp/durable-d7adec4b/script.sh: 1: docker: not found

Comment: Hi, could you add your `Dockerfile` ? Why do you want to manage Jenkins user group in Windows ? I'm not sure to understand but your error seems to be related with the fact that you don't implement any docker in docker solution.

Comment: @JoffreyK i did add my dockerfile now , for windows , it's the os where jenkins is installed

Comment: Ok, did you add the docker plugin in your Jenkins configuration ? If docker is properly installed on your machine, the error sounds like Jenkins runtime doesn't find your docker location, could you show your PATH before the build stage ? (ex: `echo ${env.PATH}`)

Comment: @JoffreyK , docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v  jenkins/jenkins:lts

Comment: so you're jenkins is in a container ? I think it's the good way but you need to mount your docker.dock (i'll post an answer).

Answer (score 6):

If you try to run Jenkins inside a container instead :

```
docker run -u 0 --privileged --name jenkins -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Of course you could replace `$(which docker)` directly by your docker path if your host machine doesn't recognize the command.

You should be able to run docker command inside your pipeline.

Comment: The question suggests a Windows host, and `$(which docker)` won't be a runnable binary in a Linux container.  The linked question discusses how to build a custom image that contains a usable binary.

Comment: @DavidMaze I disagree, the question is related with Jenkins which is not able to use docker engine, it may be due to Windows that why I suggest to run it inside a docker container with root right, docker sock and docker installation mounted. About `$(which docker)` I don't understand your point, for me it's off topic, no one suggest to run it in a container. If the command doesn't work on your machine you just need to replace it by the correct path.

Comment: More broadly, with things like shared library dependencies, even if the host and container are the same OS, the host's `docker` binary might not be runnable inside the container.  The first iteration of the typical "mount the Docker socket" advice also bind-mounted the `docker` binary, but more recent advice is to install the `docker` CLI tool in your image and only bind-mount the socket.

Comment: @DavidMaze ok thanks for the clarification. So every time you need to docker in docker you suggest to build your own image with at least docker cli installed ?

Comment: Yes.  In general, an image should contain all of its own source code, library dependencies, and external-binary dependencies.  You shouldn't be using bind mounts to inject binaries or libraries in most cases.

Comment: @DavidMaze So what are the solution for jenkins is container?

Comment: The linked question has both descriptions of installing Docker as a global tool and building a custom Dockerfile for it.

Comment: What about docker compose jenkins installation